# Cut and paste does not work

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard, cut-and-paste

As above, suddenly I cannot cut/copy-paste anymore in my windows XP host. I work on a VDI and I get the error message "Cannot empty the clipboard" on trying to cut/copy and paste.

What could be the problem?

( some of the forums suggest closing down any open remote connections but I cannot do this as I need to copy over stuff into these sessions, especially required for some critical tasks that I am runnign remotely) 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some program opened the clipboard exclusively for update, then went to sleep while still locking out the clipboard, maybe waiting for some user-input.

If you're using remote sessions that share your local clipboard, this only adds more possibilities to which program is guilty.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was sorted by logging off and logging back on. I am still not sure what caused this though - any thoughts? Recording the workaround here for reference.